# ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindById wants to invoke findOne, which I'am not allowed to declare on my Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, repository

using

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
        <!-- persistency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
...
    </dependencies>
```

following code

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractEnumEntityRepository<E extends AbstractEnumEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<E, ID> {    
    Optional<E> findById(ID id);
    boolean existsById(ID id);
    Iterable<E> findAll();
    Iterable<E> findAllById(final Iterable<ID> ids);
    long count();
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface EnTaskStateRepository extends AbstractEnumEntityRepository<EnTaskState, Short> {
}
```

yields

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Repository doesn't have a find-one-method declared!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.lambda$invokeFindById$1(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindById(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
```

when I want to use the `EnTaskStateRepository`.

After I add the findOne method and update `AbstractEnumEntityRepository` to

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractEnumEntityRepository<E extends AbstractEnumEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<E, ID> {    
    E findOne(ID id);
    Optional<E> findById(ID id);
    boolean existsById(ID id);
    Iterable<E> findAll();
    Iterable<E> findAllById(final Iterable<ID> ids);
    long count();
}
```

I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type ... ... !
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
```

exception during server startup,

but when I change `AbstractEnumEntityRepository` to

```
public interface AbstractEnumEntityRepository<E extends AbstractEnumEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<E, ID> {    // TODO revert to read-only repo
}
```

everything works fine,
but I don't want the `AbstractEnumEntityRepository` to expose update/delete methods.

How can this be achieved?

I think ReflectionRepositoryInvoker should invoke a find-by-id method properly, without throwing false exceptions.

Comment: Looks like your dependencies are a mess and you are mixing versions of a framework. I suspect you manually added spring data dependencies leading to incompatible versions.

Comment: hello @M.Deinum - I've added relevant pom parts to the post - don't think the versions could get mixed.